# A case when you can't make processing idempotent

Tags: design-patterns

I have just been confirmed for an interview and one of the hint questions given by the recruiter was:

```
"Explain Idempotency and a case when you can't make processing idempotent"
```

I understand Idempotency but cannot figure out when it can't be used.

Comment: It's generally going to depend on the requirements of the system.  For example, all changes in Git are deliberately tracked via an almost-immutable version history.  So reverting back to earlier versions in git always creates a new entry in the commit history rather than rewriting the history.    (Of course, git does technically allow you to rewrite history if absolutely necessary, but that sort of action in git is frequently undesirable).  However, that means changes in git generally can't be idempotent.

Comment: [An idempotent random number generator comes to mind.](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Answer (score 7):

You can't make something idempotent when you know the transition you want to make but not the ending state. For example, toggling a light switch. Since you don't know whether it will end up on or off, you have to pay attention to how many times you do it.

Note there's usually a different idempotent operation that leaves you in the same state. If the light is currently off, "turn light on" has the same effect as "toggle light switch." However, if you have no way of determining whether the light is currently on or off, you have no way of choosing the idempotent operation that's equivalent to toggling the switch.

Answer (score 7):

A very simple real-world programming example for an operation which cannot be made idempotent in a sensible manner is logging. A logging function is expected to append lines (maybe combined with a timestamp or an increasing ordinal number) to a log file. Two calls to the same log function, even with the same arguments, should result in two lines in the file **by design**.

Of course, one can redesign a logging API artificially to make it idempotent (by  letting the caller provide the ordinal or time stamp as an additional parameter, to identify duplicate calls), but that would not result in a very user-friendly API and bears the risk of making the logging error-prone.

Even more simple, the "append" operation of any kind of list-like container would not make sense if it would behave idempotent. Calling `mylist.append(item)` n times should add exactly n entries to the list, that would be the usual expectation. Note this does not hold for a corresponding "remove" operation: for something like `mylist.remove(item)`, idempotent behaviour can be exactly what is expected (first time the item is removed, second time nothing happens to the list, not even an exception).

Answer (score 1):

You might be familiar with the common example that often is used to explain dirty-read/write problems: adding and subtracting from a bank account.  The point of the example is that if we both read the amount add to it and then write it back, one actor can overwrite the results of the other.

This kind of activity is also non-idempotent.  Anytime you are adding or subtracting from a balance, you cannot execute the change more than once and have the result be correct.  This should be fairly intuitive.  Adding 100 to a number twice will not result in the same total as adding 100 to that number once.

We can restructure the problem to make it idempotent.  Instead of just tracking the total and modifying it, we create transactions keyed by id.  Now the balance is the sum of all the transactions and a duplicate transaction doesn't get applied.

These kinds of situations abound.  Online ordering is a good example.  If you submit a purchase get a browser error and refresh, you might get a warning about resubmitting.  You might very well end up with two copies of Benny Hill's greatest skits which is definitely a different result than just getting one.

Answer (score 1):

All very good answers.
I just wanted to add on those:

There are several scenarios where you might not be able to make jobs idempotent.

For example, if you have a legacy code, which copies bunch of transactions from may be a file into a database. Now this operation is not idempotent. If accidentally run this job twice and there is no check whether similar record exists(let's assume), you will end up with duplicate records.

Suppose we want to run these jobs in parallel, as of with this legacy setup it is quite hard. As result, you can not make them idempotent